# WingIDE brace matching colours

Tags: python, wing-ide

Has anyone figured out a way to change the brace matching colours in WingIDE?  I have managed to manually port my favourite colour scheme across from my text editor and the default green just doesn't do it for me.  I've been unable to find instructions on how to do this in the UI, user manual and mailing lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've contacted Wingware support and they have confirmed that there is no way to set the brace matching colour.